# PHPExcel dont read my xls file

Tags: php, phpexcel

When I load any file xls, but always gives the text. I do all this: DOM ELEMENT: HTML DOM ELEMENT: BODY DOM ELEMENT: P START OF PARAGRAPH: END OF PARAGRAPH: FLUSH CELL: A1 => ÐÏ

`$ aSheet = $ objPHPExcel-> getActiveSheet ();`

There is no data from external files what to do?

My code:

```
function getXLS($xls) {
    include_once '/server_name/public_html/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xls);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $aSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $array = array();
    foreach($aSheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $item = array();
        foreach($cellIterator as $cell) {
            array_push($item, $cell->getCalculatedValue());
        }
        return $array;
    }

    $excel_file = $_FILES['excel_file'];
    if( $excel_file )
        $excel_file = $_FILES['excel_file']['tmp_name'];
    if($_FILES['excel_file']['tmp_name']) {
        $xlsData = getXLS($excel_file); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those error messages are old debug code for reading an HTML file. PHPExcel has identified the file you're loading as HTML rather than a real .xls file, and is using the HTML Reader. Unfortunately, I left some diagnostics in the code that should have been removed before release.

To resolve, edit the HTML Reader file, and comment out any line that echoes anything

However, on closer inspection it actually looks like as though there is HTML markup wrapped around the bytestream data for a genuine Excel file (open the file in a text editor to see what I mean). However this file is being generated, it's being corrupted by this, making it unreadable. You need to fix the code that is creating this file.

Comment: xls file I created Excel. Can be a problem in version php Version 5.3.3?

Comment: but the file is parsed XLSX fine. Why not parsing XLS?

Comment: Please read what I said: the file you're loading is NOT a valid xls file; it's got an HTML wrapper around the xls datastream.... that is INVALID. You need to fix whatever created the file. This is NOT a PHP problem or a PHPExcel problem; it is a problem with whatever script was used to create the file

Comment: The fact is that the files I generate script - I create them in Microsoft Excel 2007, save in xls and upload

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and tell me if the first few characters look HTML markup or not; the fact that your original posting identifies `DOM ELEMENT: HTML DOM ELEMENT: BODY DOM ELEMENT: P START OF PARAGRAPH: END OF PARAGRAPH` tells me that there's HTML there: the `ÐÏ` should be the opening characters of an xls file: I don't know where the html is coming from, but that's what PHPExcel is finding

Comment: Please explain to me one thing, if you can. Why extension xlsx is okay? may need to add in my code some checking version excell?

Comment: So I can see from line 5 in that picture.... the beginning of the file should start at line 1

Comment: Extension has no real meaning.... it's the content of the file that makes a difference. Anybody can rename a file and give it a different extension; or write a file in CSV format and give it an xls extension, but that doesn't make it an xls file. Your file with an extension of xls is NOT a BIFF format Excel file; your xlsx file probably was a genuine OfficeOpenXML file

Comment: this is my code. can check with the stored file phpexcell and xls file?

Comment: <form name="exc_upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" class="upl" name="excel_file"/>
      <input type="button" value="Go" 
       onClick="javascript:if(document.exc_upload.excel_file.value.length==0) { alert('No file'); return; }; submit();">
</form>

Comment: <?php
function getXLS($xls){
 include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xls);
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $aSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
 $array = array();
 foreach($aSheet->getRowIterator() as $row){
  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $item = array();

Comment: foreach($cellIterator as $cell){
   array_push($item, iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $cell->getCalculatedValue()));
  }
  array_push($array, $item);
 }
 return $array;
}

$excel_file = $_FILES['excel_file'];
if( $excel_file )
 $excel_file = $_FILES['excel_file']['tmp_name'];
if($_FILES['excel_file']['tmp_name']){
 $xlsData = getXLS($excel_file); //извлеаем данные из XLS
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($xlsData); echo "</pre>";

Comment: Checking the PHPExcel code will make no difference... the load doesn't recognise it as an Excel BIFF file, so switches to an identify mode which recognises the first few characters of the file as HTML markup, so it uses the HTML Loader. Check the file in a text editor before you upload it

Comment: looked for standard examples. The script in the file / PHP Excel/Tests/20read excel5.php should also parse the KFL file, but there too the same error. both files from the standard manual, but I still have a bug. What do you think?    http://pic2me.ru/pics/513cdd3a6ec27.png

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever. I have no idea what a KFL file is or what it has to do with PHPExcel. I've told you why your file isn't loading... either that, or you've found a bug that nobody else in the world has ever encountered before. If you can't show me lines 1-4 of your file in a text editor, I'm going to retire to a monastery in Siberia and stop trying to help people

Comment: If the problem is not solved, I will go with you to the monastery)))